# How do I connect to an already existing SQLite database using node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js

Recently, I've been trying to work on adding a database to my Discord bot. I have been able to create the database and it is working perfectly fine, however, I want to make another command that has access to the existing database for any updates or changes I may want to make to it. I do not know how to connect to that database in a different JavaScript file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide us with your current approach (code-wise) to connecting to the db?

Comment: Yes, well I was able to figure this out just now. Before, I was thinking that I'd have to approach it a different way but it was as simple as:

`const sqlite = require("sqlite3").verbose();

const db = new sqlite.Database("./Database/Informtation.db", function (err) {

if (err) {

return console.error(err);

} else {

console.log("Connected to the database.");

});`

However, thank you very much for the reply. :)